# Is there a way to determine if a clip is audio or video as a project item?

Tags: javascript, sdk, adobe-premiere

I'm coding a Premiere plugin using the SDK provided by Adobe. I want my function to be able to be sensitive to whether the media is audio only or video (with or without audio), e.g. whether it's a .wav or a .mp4. I want this to happen before any clips are on any timelines, so I can't use the track.mediaType attribute.

I am trying to do this when the media is a project item but am not finding anything in the documentation (https://premiere-scripting-guide.readthedocs.io/4%20-%20Project%20Item%20object/projectItem.html?highlight=mediaType)

For now, this is what I'm doing:

```
GetProjectItemType: function (projectItem){
        if (projectItem.name.includes("wav") || projectItem.name.includes("mp3") || projectItem.name.includes("AIFF") )
            return "Audio"; 
        else
            return "Video"; 
    }
```

Comment: I can not comment yet, not enough reputation. I have not used this myself but as per the documentation suggests, `getProjectMetadata()` might be a good place to start with if you haven't already?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function that you can use referenced in the Adobe-CEP/Samples

projectItem.type

https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Samples/blob/f86975c3689e29df03e7d815c3bb874045b7f991/PProPanel/jsx/PPRO/Premiere.jsx#L1614

ex.

```
if ((projectItem.type === ProjectItemType.CLIP) || (projectItem.type === ProjectItemType.FILE)) {

}
```

this can help you differentiate between other projectItems such as Bins, Clips and Files and you can use this in combination with your current implementation to ensure you have either audio or video projectItem and not bin

Answer (score 0):

I used getProjectColumnsMetadata() and check to see the Audio and Video info, if they are set to "" I assume they are Video/Audio clips.

```
// JSON polyfill
"object" != typeof JSON && (JSON = {}), function () { "use strict"; var rx_one = /^[\],:{}\s]*$/, rx_two = /\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, rx_three = /"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, rx_four = /(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, rx_escapable = /[\\"\u0000-\u001f\u007f-\u009f\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g, rx_dangerous = /[\u0000\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff]/g, gap, indent, meta, rep; function f(t) { return t < 10 ? "0" + t : t } function this_value() { return this.valueOf() } function quote(t) { return rx_escapable.lastIndex = 0, rx_escapable.test(t) ? '"' + t.replace(rx_escapable, function (t) { var e = meta[t]; return "string" == typeof e ? e : "\\u" + ("0000" + t.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4) }) + '"' : '"' + t + '"' } function str(t, e) { var r, n, o, u, f, a = gap, i = e[t]; switch (i && "object" == typeof i && "function" == typeof i.toJSON && (i = i.toJSON(t)), "function" == typeof rep && (i = rep.call(e, t, i)), typeof i) { case "string": return quote(i); case "number": return isFinite(i) ? String(i) : "null"; case "boolean": case "null": return String(i); case "object": if (!i) return "null"; if (gap += indent, f = [], "[object Array]" === Object.prototype.toString.apply(i)) { for (u = i.length, r = 0; r < u; r += 1)f[r] = str(r, i) || "null"; return o = 0 === f.length ? "[]" : gap ? "[\n" + gap + f.join(",\n" + gap) + "\n" + a + "]" : "[" + f.join(",") + "]", gap = a, o } if (rep && "object" == typeof rep) for (u = rep.length, r = 0; r < u; r += 1)"string" == typeof rep[r] && (o = str(n = rep[r], i)) && f.push(quote(n) + (gap ? ": " : ":") + o); else for (n in i) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i, n) && (o = str(n, i)) && f.push(quote(n) + (gap ? ": " : ":") + o); return o = 0 === f.length ? "{}" : gap ? "{\n" + gap + f.join(",\n" + gap) + "\n" + a + "}" : "{" + f.join(",") + "}", gap = a, o } } "function" != typeof Date.prototype.toJSON && (Date.prototype.toJSON = function () { return isFinite(this.valueOf()) ? this.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + f(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "-" + f(this.getUTCDate()) + "T" + f(this.getUTCHours()) + ":" + f(this.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + f(this.getUTCSeconds()) + "Z" : null }, Boolean.prototype.toJSON = this_value, Number.prototype.toJSON = this_value, String.prototype.toJSON = this_value), "function" != typeof JSON.stringify && (meta = { "\b": "\\b", "\t": "\\t", "\n": "\\n", "\f": "\\f", "\r": "\\r", '"': '\\"', "\\": "\\\\" }, JSON.stringify = function (t, e, r) { var n; if (indent = gap = "", "number" == typeof r) for (n = 0; n < r; n += 1)indent += " "; else "string" == typeof r && (indent = r); if ((rep = e) && "function" != typeof e && ("object" != typeof e || "number" != typeof e.length)) throw new Error("JSON.stringify"); return str("", { "": t }) }), "function" != typeof JSON.parse && (JSON.parse = function (text, reviver) { var j; function walk(t, e) { var r, n, o = t[e]; if (o && "object" == typeof o) for (r in o) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (void 0 !== (n = walk(o, r)) ? o[r] = n : delete o[r]); return reviver.call(t, e, o) } if (text = String(text), rx_dangerous.lastIndex = 0, rx_dangerous.test(text) && (text = text.replace(rx_dangerous, function (t) { return "\\u" + ("0000" + t.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4) })), rx_one.test(text.replace(rx_two, "@").replace(rx_three, "]").replace(rx_four, ""))) return j = eval("(" + text + ")"), "function" == typeof reviver ? walk({ "": j }, "") : j; throw new SyntaxError("JSON.parse") }) }();

// Get the column value matching the column name
function getColumnValue(obj, columnName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if (obj[i].ColumnName === columnName) {
            return obj[i].ColumnValue;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function hasAudio(projectItem) {
    var hasAudio = getColumnValue(JSON.parse(projectItem.getProjectColumnsMetadata()), "Audio Info");
    retrun typeof hasAudio != undefined && hasAudio != "" && hasAudio.length > 0;
}

function hasVideo(projectItem) {
    var hasVideo = getColumnValue(JSON.parse(projectItem.getProjectColumnsMetadata()), "Video Info");
    return typeof hasVideo != undefined && hasVideo != "" && hasVideo.length > 0;
}
```